# Always initialize variables in C

Tags: c, variables, initialization

Some programmers say that you should always declare all variables in a beginning of a sequence (function) first in C although it is not necessary anymore since C99. Is it also a good idea to initialize all variables at the beginning or is it a waste of processor time?

Comment: any optimization step would initialize your variables in whatever way is best, do whatever makes your code clear

Comment: always initalize your variables when you declare them. Always declare them as close to where you need them (ie not at the start). The second is a style issue, but is the generally accepted one

Comment: Stop worrying about optimizing (*wasting processor time*) unless you've got a performance issue in your code and a profiler says something is a bottleneck. When you've gotten your code so well written that the only bottlenecks you've hit are variable initializations, you can stop coding, because you've become a true Programming God.

Comment: My preference is to define variables at the start of the function. Given that functions should ideally not be too complicated, is there any real need to define variables at block scope? Aside: another "advance" in C which I can't see the need for (and never use) is the formal boolean type.

Comment: @pm100 'always initalize your variables when you declare them' well, what it you don't know what to initialize them to at that time?

Comment: @MartinJames a sensible "default" value? Or a specific out-of-limit value that you can trap without relying on the compiler to find an uninitialised value?

Comment: @MArtinJames then declare them when you do know the value. By definition you dont need them till then

Comment: a) Consider that if you do write dummy values to your variables _just for the sake of initialization_, tools like Valgrind may fail to detect actual errors. Valgrind will detect reading  'unwritten' memory.  b) If you keep your functions short, the problem tends to go away since the code is so much clearer. c) If you use C89 decl (at top of block) and you want to assert() some condition before assigning, well, then you have a problem if you initialize at declaration...

Comment: @BjornA. Very interesting [1st point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040329/alway-initialize-variables-in-c/45040827#comment77057566_45040329).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Some programmers say that you should always declare all variables in a beginning of a sequence (function) first in C ...

I find declaring variables close to  where there are used first is better. [@pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040329/alway-initialize-variables-in-c#comment77054897_45040329)

Yet this is a style issue.  Best to follow your group's coding standard.

> Is it also a good idea to initialize all variables at the beginning or is it a waste of processor time?

With simple variables this is not a "waste of processor time".

With long arrays, there is a small chance of significant delay.

```
#define N 4096
char buf[N];
// or
char buf[N] = { 0 };
if (fread(buf, sizeof buf[0], N, ...
```

Perform "unneeded" initialization per your group's coding standard.

Consider 4 cases: 3 have potential UB

```
// No initialization
char buf1[N];
fgets(buf1, sizeof buf1, stdin);
fputs(buf1, stdout);

// Initialization
char buf2[N] = {0};
fgets(buf2, sizeof buf2, stdin);
fputs(buf2, stdout);

// No initialization, early assignment
char buf3[N];
buf3[0] = '\0';
fgets(buf3, sizeof buf3, stdin);
fputs(buf3, stdout);

// No initialization, test function result that populates buf4
char buf4[N];
if (fgets(buf4, sizeof buf4, stdin)) {
  fputs(buf4, stdout);
}
```

> Only `if (fgets(buf4, sizeof buf4, stdin))` is proper protection against a read error which ends with "the array contents are indeterminate".

I neither critique for nor against unnecessary initialization as 1) compilers often (not always) detect and warn about missing initialization/assignment 2) Coding problems I see tend to exist in not examining error status and 3) as with holy war issues like [Indent style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)  this, I follow my group's coding standard - whatever it is.

Comment: as automatic variables are normally declared without initializing them, allocating a large array is the same as allocating a small variable.... only the value added to the stack pointer to reserve the space needed changes.  This is different if you have to initialize automatic variables, or with parameters (that are always initialized).

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes, it is always better choice to initialize variables (*local scoped, automatic storage, specifically*) upon definition. Doing so avoids the possibility of using unitialized values, which *may* lead to undefined behaviour.

For example, a simple case,

```
int x;

//...after some code
if (/*some options*/) x = 0;

//after some more code

if (x == 5) {....
```

the above snippet can certainly lead to UB in case the `if` evaluates to false. However, while defining `x`, if we initialize, like

```
 int x = -1;
```

then, at least, we can avoid the UB.

*Note: This does not justify ignoring compiler warning (possible use of unitialized variable) though, it's just an example.*

That said, with proper optimization enabled, for a compiler it does not matter where you define your variable, but for the readability purpose, you should always define the variables close/prior to it's usage. That's again, a *recommendation*, not a *rule*.

There's a nice Q&A on [softwareengineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223862/110624), do read that.

Comment: Sometimes `/* "old-style" comments */` are preferable :)

Answer (score 2):

You confuse *initialization* with *declaration*. Initialization is giving a variable its initial value, and if you can, it's good style to initialize variables. You **must** give a variable a value before you use it anyways.

But your question seems to be about *where to declare* variables. The commonly accepted best practice is *as close to the usage as possible*.

With C89, variables must be declared at the beginning of a block. The only reason I could think of to stick to this rule (short of being compatible with a very old standard) is that it encourages you to keep your functions and blocks short. But I'm not in favor of such arguments, because you can still keep functions and blocks short (definitely good practice) while declaring variables only when they're actually used, which makes the code slightly better readable.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! But no, I've actually understand the difference between an initialization and declaration. I would say declaration means "creating" a variable and initialization gives the variable a start value (just like you). I personally have chosen to follow the old rule. Based on good designating names which you see first then it is easier to guess what the sequence of code does, I think.

Comment: @HenryWeinert also the difference between "declaration" and "implementation". For a variable `extern int i;` is a declaration but `int i;` is its implementation. For a function the prototype `int myfunc(int val);` is a declaration but `int myfunc(int val) { return val + 1; }` is its implementation.

Comment: @WeatherVane There is also the difference of variables  `int i_at_file_scope;` as a _tentative definition_ and `int i_at_function_scope;` as a _definition_.

Comment: @chux indeed a variable (unintialised) may be defined more than once at file scope, but not at function scope.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers are smart enough to optimize your code doesn't matter whether you define variables at the beginning or at the middle of a code scope.

In many cases, defining a variable right the time you need it looks more readable since you can easily trace back what type of the variable is and what is the variable used for (especially with very-long code snippet).

However, initializing variables as soon as defining it is a good behavior since it help avoiding undefined behaviors due to accessing un-initialized variables.

Answer (score 1):

*Just to point out a dissonant view (I agree initialization is good).*

When the variable is going to be used as the counter in a `for` loop, I find that initializing it looks worse than assignment

```
int i = 0;              // initialization
for (; i < 100; i++) {
    // code, code, code
    if (foo == bar) i = 999;
    // code, code, code
}
if (i == 999) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

---

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { // assignment
    // code, code, code
    if (foo == bar) i = 999;
    // code, code, code
}
if (i == 999) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```